# jQuery AJAX call broken under PHP 8.X (PHP 8 Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists() error)

Tags: php, http-status-code-500, php-8.1

I will try to be as much explicative as possible.

I have a PHP+jQuery application (some sort of a text game) where the system works reading and writing JSON files with AJAX all the time. Everything is absolutely **perfect under PHP 7.4**, however, when I **upgrade to 8.0 or 8.1** (my hosting is forcing me) the AJAX breaks.

Inspecting the JS console, right after the very first AJAX call, I get a ERROR 500. So, I assumed it was happening in the PHP side and **I was right**. I did take a look in the apache logs and found a PHP fatal error happening there — But note that under PHP7.4, there are no problems at all.

**The error in my Apache log:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists():
Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array,
stdClass given in /home/xxx/zzz.com/motor/FileDriver.php:36,
referer: https://zzz.com/yyy/xxx/
```

**And this is the PHP file where the error happens, line 36:**

```
function save() {
    $n = func_num_args();
    $g = func_get_args();

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($g[0]));
    
    if (!array_key_exists($g[1], $data))
        $data->{$g[1]} = new StdClass();

    if (($n == 4) && (!array_key_exists($g[2], $data->{$g[1]})))
        $data->{$g[1]}->{$g[2]} = new StdClass();

    if ($n == 3)
        $data->{$g[1]} = $g[2];
    else if ($n == 4)
        $data->{$g[1]}->{$g[2]} = $g[3];

    unlink($g[0]);
    file_put_contents($g[0], json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

**The error happens right here:**

```
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($g[0]));
    // THE ERROR BELOW!
    if (!array_key_exists($g[1], $data))
        $data->{$g[1]} = new StdClass();
```

I tried to add the **$assoc** parameter to PHP **json_decode() function**, but it did not help. I really have no idea how to solve that, other than downgrading to PHP 7.4... however, can't do it anymore.

EDITED: Removed irrelevant code, image and information.

EDITED2: Adjusted the title to a more explicative sentence.

Comment: Well if you changed PHP version, the javascript code has nothing to do with it

Comment: You have an error in a function, so how do you call the function! And what parameters do you pass

Comment: PHP 8 got more particular about data types. No longer can you throw anything at anything and hope for the best

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to Code, Data or Error Messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: The error says it all: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists():`.  You need to focus on Line 36 in your PHP code.  NOTE: 30 seconds after I typed this comment, I noticed an excellent reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75892872/421195. Please "accept" and "upvote" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AJAX call hasn't failed. The error message clearly points at PHP, so all this JavaScript is irrelevant.

Looking at the error message and the PHP code you have posted the variable `$data` is an object.

The documentation for `array_key_exists()` says this:

> For backward compatibility reasons, array_key_exists() will also
> return true if key is a property defined within an object given as
> array. This behaviour is deprecated as of PHP 7.4.0, and removed as of
> PHP 8.0.0.
>
> To check whether a property exists in an object, property_exists()
> should be used.

You should update line 36 to this:

```
if (!property_exists($data,$g[1]))
```

Note that the order of parameters is reversed from `array_key_exists()`

Comment: Thank you, Tangentially. I feel ashamed of myself. I have worked a lot with "property_exists" in other instances of my code and missed a so trivial solution here, at this point.

Thanks, really!
\m/

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular: your reply is *MUCH* better for this particular "symptom" (PHP 8 `Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists()` error) than the so-called "duplicate".  +1.